# Trying to save recyclerView to sharedPreferences

Tags: java, android

I am trying to save the recyclerView content to sharedPreferences and it doesn't seem to be working.  I'm quite new to the whole android dev and coding thing so I have no doubt that my code is archaic.

At the moment it will display a list with some strings in it and when the add button is pressed it adds "Cats" to the list and is meant to save the addition to shared prefs.  When i quit out of the app and go back into it the new entries are not there meaning either there is a problem with saving, or with loading.....or both.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements acronymsList.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

SharedPreferences acronymEntryPrefs;
public String[] fromAcronymPrefs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    acronymsList homeFragment = new acronymsList();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.mainFragmentFrame, homeFragment).commit();

    acronymEntryPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("ACRONYM_ENTRIES", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    getPrefs();
    fromAcronymPrefs = new String[4];
    fromAcronymPrefs[0] = "cats";
    fromAcronymPrefs[1] = "goats";
    fromAcronymPrefs[2] = "pigs";
    fromAcronymPrefs[3] = "dogs";
    acronymsList.getVar(fromAcronymPrefs);
}

public void getPrefs() {
    int size = acronymEntryPrefs.getInt("array_size", 0);
    fromAcronymPrefs = new String[size];
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
        acronymEntryPrefs.getString("array_" + i, null);
}
```

acronymsList.java

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_acronyms_list, container, false);
    acronymList = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.acronymRecyclerView);
    addNewEntry = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.addBtn);

    adapter = new acronymListAdapter(getActivity(), getData());
    acronymList.setAdapter(adapter);
    acronymList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    return layout;
}

public static List<acronymEntry> getData() {
    List<acronymEntry> data = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] acronymTitles = fromAcronymPrefs;

    for(int i=0; i< acronymTitles.length; i++){
        acronymEntry current = new acronymEntry();
        current.title = acronymTitles[i];
        data.add(current);
    }

    return data;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    acronymEntryPrefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("ACRONYM_ENTRIES", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    addNewEntry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            List<String> tempArray = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(int i=0; i< fromAcronymPrefs.length; i++){
                String current = new String();
                current = fromAcronymPrefs[i];
                tempArray.add(current);
            }
            tempArray.add("Cats");

            fromAcronymPrefs = tempArray.toArray(new String[tempArray.size()]);
            updateAdapter = new acronymListAdapter(getActivity(), getData());
            acronymList.swapAdapter(updateAdapter, false);
            savePrefs(fromAcronymPrefs);
        }
    });
}

public void savePrefs(String[] forSave) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = acronymEntryPrefs.edit();
    edit.putInt("array_size", forSave.length);
    for(int i=0;i<fromAcronymPrefs.length; i++)
        edit.putString("array_" + i, fromAcronymPrefs[i]);
    edit.commit();
}
```

Hopefully thats enough to go off.  Let me know if there is any more code needed.

Comment: Thats not a good idea to save whole data to shared preferences, as Shared Preferences only support primitive data types (int, string, boolean). To persist data into app either use DB (Sqlite) or create some data structure classed to retain data temporarily.

Comment: Your `fromAcronymPrefs` is of size 4. Then it will show only the 4 elements. Also its recommended to use `Sqllite` database to store lots of data than `SharedPreference`.